# Expected argument of type src\Entity\... given at property path src\Entity\

Tags: forms, symfony

I try to do an embedded form and have tow errors :
1-when i click on add Add experience : i get 2 sub forms experience
2- when i save after i add experience i have this error --Expected argument of type "src\Entity\Experience", "App\Entity\Experience" given at property path "experiences".---

[https://i.imgur.com/WMtkiQC.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DCN7i.jpg)

```
if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            // ... maybe do some form processing, like saving the Task and Tag objects

            $personne = $form->getData();
            $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $entityManager->persist($personne);
            $entityManager->flush();

            return $this->render('base.html.twig', [

            ]);
```

[Controller](https://pastebin.com/Z87Ekjze)

[Experience Entity](https://pastebin.com/nu6L50kC)

[Personne Entity](https://pastebin.com/e5s2VAJC)

[Experience Form](https://pastebin.com/agQfqq8w)

[Personne Form](https://pastebin.com/TWZYbtsB)

[Twig Template](https://pastebin.com/Dahaz4Uj)

Comment: Please reformat your question. The image you added is not helpful as it's extremely long and unreadable. Please also add the full error message and limit the code example a snippet from the calling code and code that might be related.

Comment: The message `Expected argument of type "src\Entity\Experience"` hints at a problem with a class having the wrong namespace. Maybe use a project wide search to see if anything references `src`, instead of `App`

Comment: I upload the image and the error message  is "Expected argument of type "src\Entity\Experience", "App\Entity\Experience" given at property path "experiences"."

Comment: Thank you very much but i haven't solve the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the problem could be here https://pastebin.com/e5s2VAJC (`Personne` entity) on line 9. Instead of the `use src\Entity\Experience;` you should use `use App\Entity\Experience;`

Comment: Tank you very much benedya the error was resolved. But the other part of the problem is when i click add experience two forms are added !! not 1.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/DCN7i.jpg

Comment: You need to move the `{% block javascripts %}` outside of the `{% block body %}` like https://pastebin.com/zPFsR97r